# Error while executing the command ./graphhopper import <berlin.osm.pbf>

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, graphhopper, mapsforge

[image]

I get the error message when I execute `./graphhopper` import `<berlin.osm.pbf>` for creating the graph data.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug [fixed 5 days ago](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/commit/becfcff08a01eff955a1d9e774fe8b9d6759d80b). In those cases you can always try a stable release e.g. switch to 0.7 branch before the import:

```
git checkout 0.7
```

Comment: Can I run the bash command "./graphhopper import .osm.pbf " in app programmatically to generate routing data? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but not on Android: call hopper.importOrLoad() https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/routing.md